# How can i pass database name dynamically in ssis execute sql task

Tags: dynamic, ssis, database-connection, ssis-connection-manager

In my server there are multiple databases. Hence having multiple connection manager for each db on server.
Would like to pass database name as parameter in executesql task, so that I can reduce the no of connection managers.
Something like below would be most preferable,

```
use ? 
select * from tablename
```

Comment: Sounds awful... I guess the solution with multiple con. managers (or at least multiple parameters which are interpreted as connectionstring by the expression on one con. manager) would be better... anyways: it should be possible to put an expression on your execute sql task and there you can build the statement like `"USE " + [parameter] + "; SELECT *..."`...

Comment: yes I have tried that working

Comment: with out expression any way we could configure database name at runtime of any task. I hope it is not available.

Comment: No, as far as I know there is no other possibility. Even passing the parameter to a SQL Task with dynamic SQL won't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use multipart database naming conventions. the "use database" just changes the context of your connection. Choose the database that you use most frequently as a default then use the following:

select column1, column2 from databasename.schema.tablename

You can even use it across servers if you setup linked servers. (4-part naming)

select column1, column2 from linkedserver.databasename.schema.tablename